z value in NDC outside [-1...1]
I'm trying to write a simple graphics pipeline, I encountered a problem in NDC. The coordinates are out of range from -1 to 1, while the top is clearly inside the camera pyramid (near plane at a distance of 0.01, far plane 100, view angle 90 degrees). I use the following order of matrix multiplication: the model matrix M is multiplied by the world matrix W (scaling, rotation, transfer) then by the camera view matrix V and the projection matrix P. Then I perform perspective division by w. Below is an example of calculation for vector (2,3,6)
matrices
view
In the code it now looks like this:
var M = new Vector(2,3,6)
var S = Matrix.scale(1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5)
var RX = Matrix.rotation.x(10)
var RY = Matrix.rotation.y(20)
var RZ = Matrix.rotation.z(30)
var R = Matrix.multiply.matrix(Matrix.multiply.matrix(RX, RY),RZ)
var T = Matrix.translation(1,2,3)
var W = Matrix.multiply.matrix(Matrix.multiply.matrix(S,R),T)
var WM = Matrix.multiply.vector(W,M)
// Vector {x: 2.5686, y: 6.8377, z: 14.3316, w: 1}
var V = camera.view()
var VM = Matrix.multiply.vector(V,WM)
//Vector {x: 4.1118, y: 0.5398, z: -13.0924, w: 1}
var P = camera.getProjectionMatrix()
var PM = Matrix.multiply.vector(P,VM)
//Vector {x: 0.8236, y: 0.5398, z: 13.0750, w: 13.0924}
var NDC = new Vector(PM.x/PM.w, PM.y/PM.w, PM.z/PM.w)
//Vector {x: 0.2080, y: -0.1805, z: 1.0002, w: 1}
Is the matrix multiplication sequence correct? Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I would be grateful for useful sources on this topic.
